# Quick-sorting with multiple threads leaves last 1/6 unsorted

Tags: c, multithreading, quicksort

My goal is to create a program that takes a large list of unsorted integers (1-10 million) and divides it into 6 parts where a thread concurrently sorts it. After sorting I merge it into one sorted array so I can find the median and mode quicker.

The input file will be something like this:

```
# 1000000
314
267
213
934
```

where the number following the # identifies the number of integers in the list.

Currently I can sort perfect and quickly without threading however when I began threading I ran into an issue. For a 1,000,000 data set it only sorts the first 833,333 integers leaving the last 166,666 (1/6) unsorted.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <time.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int sum; /* this data will be shared by the thread(s) */
int * bigArr;
int size;
int findMedian(int array[], int size)
{
    if (size % 2 != 0)
        return array[size / 2];

    return (array[(size - 1) / 2] + array[size / 2]) / 2;
}
/*compare function for quicksort*/
int _comp(const void* a, const void* b) {
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}

/*This function is the problem method*/
/*indicate range of array to be processed with the index(params)*/
void *threadFct(int param)
{
    int x= size/6;
    if(param==0)x= size/6;
    if(param>0&&param<5)x= (size/6)*param;
    if(param==5)x= (size/6)*param+ (size%size/6);/*pass remainder into last thread*/
    qsort((void*)bigArr, x, sizeof(bigArr[param]), _comp);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *source;
    int i =0;

    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];

    if(argc!=2){
        printf("Error. please enter ./a followed by the file name");
        return -1;}

    source= fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (source == NULL) { /*reading error msg*/
        printf("Error. File not found.");
        return 1;
    }
    int count= 0;
    while (!feof (source)) {
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof (buffer), source)) {
            if(count==0){  /*Convert string to int using atoi*/
                char str[1];
                sprintf(str, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c",buffer[2],buffer[3],buffer[4],buffer[5],buffer[6],buffer[7],buffer[8],buffer[9],buffer[10]);/*get string of first */
                size= atoi(str); /* read the size of file--> FIRST LINE of file*/
                printf("SIZE: %d\n",size);
                bigArr= malloc(size*sizeof(int));
            }
            else{
                //printf("[%d]= %s\n",count-1, buffer); /*reads in the rest of the file*/
                bigArr[count-1]= atoi(buffer);
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

/*thread the unsorted array*/
    pthread_t tid[6]; /* the thread identifier */
    pthread_attr_t attr; /* set of thread attributes */

// qsort((void*)bigArr, size, sizeof(bigArr[0]), _comp);  <---- sorts array without threading
    for(i=0; i<6;i++){
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, &threadFct, i);
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("Sorted array:\n");

    for(i=0; i<size;i++){
        printf("%i \n",bigArr[i]);
    }

    fclose(source);
}
```

So to clarify the problem function is in my `threadFct()`. 
To explain what the function is doing, the param(thread number) identifies which chunk of the array to quicksort. I divide the size into 6 parts and because the it is even, the remainder of the numbers go into the last chunk. So for example, 1,000,000 integers I would have the first 5/6 sort 166,666 each and the last 1/6 would sort the remainder (166670).

I am aware that

- Multi-threading will not speed up much at all even for 10 million integers
- This is not the most efficient way to find the median/mode

Thanks for reading this and any help is received with gratitude.

Comment: Probably not related to the problem, but see: [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: You set `x = size/6` for both `param = 0` and `param = 1`.

Comment: The argument to a pthreads thread function must have type `void *`.  You are not at liberty to use a different type.  However, you can convey your integer thread number to the thread function by casting it to `void *` in `pthread_create()` and then casting it back in `threadFct`.  If your compiler is not already giving you at least two warnings about type mismatches then you need to get a better compiler.

Comment: `size%size/6` is always zero.

Comment: Since you create and join in the same loop, all 6 threads run serially anyway & so you will see no improvement in runtime:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sorting the beginning of the array in every call to `qsort`. You're only changing the number of elements that each thread sorts, by setting `x`. You're also setting `x` to the same value in threads `0` and `1`.

You need to calculate an offset into the array for each thread, which is just `size/6 * param`. The number of elements will be `size/6` except for the last chunk, which uses a modulus to get the remainder.

As mentioned in the comments, the argument to the thread function should be a pointer, not `int`. You can hide an integer in the pointer, but you need to use explicit casts.

```
void *threadFct(void* param_ptr)
{
    int param = (int)param_ptr;
    int start = size/6 * param;
    int length;
    if (param < 5) {
        length = size/6;
    } else {
        length = size - 5 * (size/6);
    }
    qsort((void*)(bigArr+start), length, sizeof(*bigArr), _comp);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

and later

```
pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, &threadFct, (void*)i);
```